# Angular ng-model not working when html is rendered by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a `jquery` plugin, that renders some html in the `DOM`. I set `ng-model` attribute to injected html in that jquery plugin.

After page loading has finished, `ng-model` doesn't bind to angular.

Attributes are added from jquery:

```
attributes: {
    dir               : "ltr",
    spellcheck        : false,
    "ng-model"        : "userContent",
    id                : "myID"
}
```

After page loading, this will be added to html:

```
<div dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" ng-model="userContent2" id="myID" contenteditable="true">Test</div>
```

**NOTE:** I tested with html, that already exist in the `DOM`. (It does't relate to contenteditable)

Comment: seems weird you would not use angular to render the html needed and just hook the JavaScript up to it.

Comment: It won't because angular needs to know about directive attributes and compile them. The plugin would need to use `$compile` to do that

Comment: have you tried to bind the userContent2 model in a things like: <span data-ng-bind-html="userContent2"></span>

Comment: What is the plugin, what does it do and how are you initializing it? See [mcve]